# (coldFusion 10) How do I capture the vertical position of a webpage?

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm using ColdFusion10. How do I capture the vertical position of a scrollbar/webpage?
I have a page in a table that has Previous and Next buttons.
Every time a user clicks the next button it loads the next number of rows, but currently the page scrolls backup to the top after every load. 
I require the page to not scroll to the top after the initial page load.
Is there a way I can capture the vertical location of the scrollbar/webpage?
Maybe I don't need to capture the current scrollbar position, but rather have it load at a certain vertical position after the first page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly; why not use a [Fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) `#` in your link?

```
<a href="mypage.cfm#foo">Next Page</a>
```

If your table has the id of foo `<table id="foo">` the browser will focus on the element when the page loads

Comment: I'm not a web developer. Let me investigate the fragment identifier # and I'll mark it as answered if I can successfully implement it in my project.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer Trust me it works, try [reading you own comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716170/coldfusion-10-how-do-i-capture-the-vertical-position-of-a-webpage/21716266?noredirect=1#comment32838543_21716266)

Comment: Slick move implementing it. Can't argue with that.

Comment: I have a form <form action="viewTable.cfm#tableDisplay"... and I named my table "tableDisplay" ColdFusion gives me an error:coldfusion.compiler.ParseException: Invalid CFML construct found on line 66 at column 32.

Comment: As `#` is a special character in ColdFusion you will need to escape it; use an extra hash, `mypage.cfm##foo`.

Comment: You only need the extra `#` if the URL is inside a  `cfoutput` block.

Comment: You need to escape a `#` anywhere it would otherwise be considered as marking the start of an expression - which includes _not just_ inside cfoutput blocks, but also in the body of tags such as cfmail and cfquery, and of course inside any strings (and thus tag attributes) too. (And you _don't_ need hashes at all when you're already dealing with an expression.)